# datetime picker not showing correctly on modal window bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-datetime-picker to show datetime picker , but for some reason on modal window is not showing correctly.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add new class</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" date-format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" hour="09" minute='00' name="time" ng-model="clas.class_.time" datetime-picker  class="form-control input-lg" tabindex="3">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="clas.create()" data-dismiss="modal">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone knows the issue?

[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYtI4.png)

Comment: Could you create a fiddle and let us know what do you meant by not showing correctly

Comment: I have attached an image where u can see that the modal window is overriding the whole window and calendar is under it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It' a CSS problem, by default *bootstrap modal* has a `z-index: 1050;`. Try to add a higher `z-index` to your *datetime-picker* like this:

```
.angularjs-datetime-picker {
    z-index:5000;
}
```

Comment: I tried to add id as inline style: style = "z-index:5000;" but still not working

Comment: Add the above CSS to your page. Because, you can't add it to '.angularjs-datetime-picker', it's an angular directive!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a z-index issue.
Try setting the modal z-index lower and/or setting the z-index of the datepicker higher in your css:

```
.modal{
   z-index: 200;
}
.datepicker{
   z-index: 999;
}
```